# windows 8 + Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on Windows 8.

Yes I can access both of them, but the process is kind of long.

In BIOS, EFI is for Windows 8, legacy support is for Ubuntu.

If I choose EFI first, the startup just go straight to Win8 without offering me a choice.
If I choose legacy first, the starup will offer me a choice between win8 and ubuntu.
But I can only choose Ubuntu. If i choose win8, there will be a mistake(file missing under configuration).

That is to say, every time i wanna switch to another OS, I have to go into BIOS and change the priority settings. I heard something about secure boot might be the cause of this situation. But the thing is that there is not even an option called "secure boot" in my BIOS, which means i cannot disable it.

All I want is that an option menu appears everytime i turn on my computer so i can easily choose what OS I want for today.

Can anyone help me plz?
Thank you very much!!

Comment: Please indicate your BootInfo URL. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 1):

choose legacy mode on bios and then try [`boot-repair`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/?source=navbar).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this on some new HP pc's.. Is yours a HP? FYI -- any new PC with the Win8 logo on it has Secure Boot.. It's in your BIOS, but every BIOS is different, so it could be hidden under a drop down sub-menu..

So far, there is no 100% sure-fire way to dual boot with a Win8 machine. Mine is even more difficult because my partial SSD is setup as a FakeRaid 0, which Linux doesn't recognize..

I have resigned myself that until they come out with a fix for dummies, I'm using Ubuntu on my Win8 PC using VmWare. The VM doesn't have the best performance, and some drivers are wonky, but it's better than messing with the BIOS and booting from a flash drive every time.

Now if you want to have JUST Ubuntu, then you should be able to do it the way you currently are doing it, but by installing it over top of Win 8.

Comment: Mine is Lenovo that i just bought

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Boot Repair in a live CD/USB session. It can work miracles for a missing entry in grub.

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu (as in the OS, not the install) onto your USB. You could do that by setting up a virtual machine and running the iso of Ubuntu on it. When installing it, you might see your USB in the list of drives. Click on your USB and let it install Ubuntu.

I've got a Lenovo Laptop and I was able to boot Ubuntu without any BIOS settings changed.

I hope that helped! ;)